# Average of raster elevation based on polygon boundaries

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, polygon, spatial-analyst, lidar

I am attempting to extract and calculate the average height of buildings using LiDAR converted to raster elevation data. I've created a DSM to cover the entire area and I am trying to extract just the buildings out, I need the average height based upon the DSM elevation pixels. How do I calculate this?

I've attempted clipping these images out according to the polygons (which created thousands of individual rasters) but still I am unsure how to get the average within the bounds of the footprint.

[image: Building with footprint outline and 10cm pixels]

Comment: Assign good ids to polygons, use zonal statistics from spatial analyst

Comment: @FelixIP, I just ran zonal stats and it worked perfectly. It's strange because I'm positive I tried it before with all different settings and it constantly failed, making me think it was the wrong approach. Thank you! - An aside - how do I verify this as 'answered'?

Comment: Glad it works, forget about it. I am sure there are multiple similar posts on this forum.

Answer (score 4):

As Felix suggested, the [Zonal Statistics](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//009z000000wt000000) tool worked. The mistake made before was not using a unique ID for the polygon 'zones'. The output worked well:

[image]

Comment: +1 For including the picture which shows what can be achieved.

Comment: +1 for feedback and reply. Legend colours ar no good though